# indexOf Error When Triggering Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript, I have the following event I am trying to trigger using jquery's [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function:

```
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  (
    // e.which == 34 ||  PAGE DOWN
    // e.which == 32 ||  SPACE
    axis == 'X' && e.which == 39 // RIGHT
    // axis == 'Y' && e.which == 40 // BOTTOM
  ) && deck.next();
  (
    // e.which == 33 || PAGE UP
    axis == 'X' && e.which == 37 // LEFT
    // axis == 'Y' && e.which == 38 // TOP
  ) && deck.prev();
});
```

I am trying to trigger this event listener using the following line:

```
$(document).trigger({eventType:"keydown", which:39});
```

However when I do this, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: q.indexOf is not a function

I would hope instead that the line triggers `deck.next();`

Please advise as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please add the portion of code where you use `indexOf`

Comment: @Bek 
`var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 39; // # Some key code value
$(document).trigger(e);` does not work for me, as that answer indicates.

Comment: @che-azeh I don't ever use that, that is just the error message jquery gives me, which is why I don't understand it. The error message is invoked after `$(document).trigger({eventType:"keydown", which:39});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add jquery event listener and then in invoke it
(you need jquery event listener because you are triggering it with jquery)

```
 $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  (
    // e.which == 34 ||  PAGE DOWN
    // e.which == 32 ||  SPACE
    axis == 'X' && e.which == 39 // RIGHT
    // axis == 'Y' && e.which == 40 // BOTTOM
  ) && deck.next();
  (
    // e.which == 33 || PAGE UP
    axis == 'X' && e.which == 37 // LEFT
    // axis == 'Y' && e.which == 38 // TOP
  ) && deck.prev();
});
```

and trigger it like this

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown"); 
e.which = 39; // # Some key code value 
$(document).trigger(e);
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why the original event listener didn't trigger? Was it because it wasn't using jquery's syntax?

Comment: added that in my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).trigger("keydown", {which: 39});
```

This is the [correct syntax](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-eventType-extraParameters)...

Comment: It does not work, do you think this is because there is an axis requirement in the event listener that needs to be included somehow?

Comment: That is for triggering the event internally. You can also do this I believe to create a "real" event https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/mjs5cfnh/

Comment: @SummerDeveloper look at my example below you need jquery event listener as it is being triggered by jquery, you can still use this syntax to trigger event though

Answer (score 1):

I think your trigger code is syntactically wrong

```
 var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
 e.which = 39;
 $(document).trigger(e);
```

Also, jquery trigger wont recognise handlers attached by plain javascript.So you have to attach handlers using jquery only. 
Something like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){});
```

or

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(event){});
```

or

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(event){});
```

Comment: It does not work, do you think this is because there is an axis requirement in the event listener that needs to be included somehow?